# Vim, terminal, or htop won't start

Tags: unity, launcher, vim, htop

Starting Vim, terminal or Htop from the Ubuntu 16.04 Unity desktop "Search your computer" doesn't work. When I select Vim for example, The Vim icon appears in the launcher and oscillates between bright and dark and then disappears. The same happens for terminal and htop (maybe others). Apps like Google, FireFox, Android Studio, Terminator, all start OK.

If I navigate to usr/share/applications in Nautilus and right click on "Terminal" and select open, the same oscillation between bright and dark happens.

I'm able to start a terminal using Ctrl-Alt-t, and I'm able to launch Vim and Htop from a terminal command line OK.

Is there a log on Ubuntu that shows me what's happening to a process that doesn't start successfully?

Any ideas on what's not setup correctly are greatly appreciated.

The terminal I am trying to launch is the one next to terminator
[Launcher showing terminal app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCU7t.png)

Here is what I see when I right click on "Terminal" [Right click on Terminal icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Axp.png)

Comment: htop or vim I could see not starting from the desktop as they require the terminal to work properly, but launching that terminal doesn't sound right.  Is there a way that you can get a screen shot of the terminal icon you are trying to run?  I am wondering if you might have had more than one installed.  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1069957/edit) your question and add the screen shot or any more details.  Thank you!

Comment: When I do Ctrl-Alt-t, my terminal is called "Root Terminal". From my processes, it looks like it's running usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator. Is the "Terminal" that I try running from "Search your computer" the same? How can I figure out if it is?

Comment: You can try Right-Clicking the icon and select the information and see if it brings up information about it, it might come up in the GNOME Software.

Comment: I tried right clicking and it doesn't give me any information. Maybe I have Unity configured incorrectly as all my icons show the same thing. I added an image of what I see when I right click.